# WPF DataGridComboboxColumn with static list displaying on editing mode only

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

So, I have a DataGridComboBoxColumn whose itemssource is set to a static list.

DatagridComboboxColumn:

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Prioridad" Width="1*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedPriorityLevel}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Key"  SelectedValuePath="Value"        ItemsSource="{StaticResource arrList}">


            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Static Resource:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <col:ArrayList x:Key="arrList">
        <col:DictionaryEntry Key="A" Value="1"/>
        <col:DictionaryEntry Key="M" Value="2"/>
        <col:DictionaryEntry Key="B" Value="3"/>
    </col:ArrayList>
</Window.Resources>
```

and  the binding is set to a field with an Enum

```
Public Enum ActionPlanPriorityLevels
Alta = 1
Media = 2
Baja = 3

End Enum
```

The problem I'm having is that the combobox is only showing in editing mode for some reason.

[image: Showing on editing mode]
[image: Not Showing]

but the selected value is not displaying

What Am I Missing?

Comment: I would say its something to do with your SelectedPriorityLevel property that your binding to. Could you share some code as to what this is

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, do you want the combobox to always be displayed or do you just want the selected value to be displayed after editing?

Comment: I want the selected value to be displayed after editing. :)

Comment: Well the SelectedPriorityLevel is a property with an enum type: Public Property SelectedPriorityLevel() As ActionPlanPriorityLevels, The Enum ActionPlanPriorityLevels has 3 options, A, M and B

Comment: So that was it. I changed the property's type to an integer and voila! now it works. Thank you so much Kezza.

Comment: The thing is you're binding to the selected value and the SelectedValuePath is pointing to Value, As your values of the dictionary entries are numbers they can be recognized as integers or strings, as I used.
Its also worth noting if you didn't set the SelectedValuePath at all it would make the selected value the complete dictionary entry (Key and Value).

Comment: That said I would probably suggest actually using an enum behind the scenes and doing something similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did the following and it seemed to work fine for me

```
<Window x:Class="Tester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <collections:ArrayList x:Key="arrList">
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="A" Value="1"/>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="M" Value="2"/>
        <collections:DictionaryEntry Key="B" Value="3"/>
    </collections:ArrayList>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Prioridad" Width="1*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedPriorityLevel}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Key"  SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{StaticResource arrList}">
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _viewmodel;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _viewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        _viewmodel.GridItems.Add(new GridItemViewModel());
        _viewmodel.GridItems.Add(new GridItemViewModel());

        this.DataContext = _viewmodel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<GridItemViewModel> _gridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridItemViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<GridItemViewModel> GridItems
    {
        get { return _gridItems; }
        set { _gridItems = value; }
    }
}

public class GridItemViewModel
{
    private string _selectedPriorityLevel;
    public string SelectedPriorityLevel
    {
        get { return _selectedPriorityLevel; }
        set { _selectedPriorityLevel = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that, it's still not displaying. Just to clarifty, the underlying object is being updated just fine. IT's just the combo is not displaying anything on the datagrid unless it's on editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property for selected value

```
 SelectedValueBinding
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270745/2470362

Comment: SelectedValueBinding is there. The other property I'm afraid doesn't exist on said column.